# Scrub through memory arbitrarily while avoiding Read Access Violations

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, memory

I'm writing a debugging tool that takes a memory address from another process and displays the memory there and also all of the memory around it.  Ordinarily, reading memory like this can cause a Read Access Violation depending on the address, but I don't want to crash if the user scrubs into memory the process doesn't own, or picks a weird address.

Given an address, even something sure to fail like `0x00000000`, how can I try to access it without aborting my program if it's in violation?

Comment: Have you tried a try-catch?   In MS C++, it does catch the ones that are newed but not the ones on the stack.  I don't know about cygwin/mingw GNU C++ or the other C++ compilers available on the windows platforms.

Comment: Use [ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) - you'll need to anyway. It does not crash the target app but simply returns failure in case the memory address isn't valid for reading.

Comment: @cup: `try catch` is for C++ exceptions, not access violations. But it's not an access violation either, as the comment above explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[VirtualQueryEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-virtualqueryex) can be used to iterate all pages of any process you have access to in order to check page protection.

[QueryWorkingSetEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-queryworkingsetex) is similar but filtered to *paged in memory*, otherwise known as the [working set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/working-set), and can provide more detailed information.

[ReadProcessMemory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-readprocessmemory) is, at its most basic, a memcpy wrapped in an exception handler from kernel. You won't ever crash using this (properly) and can check [GetLastError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/errhandlingapi/nf-errhandlingapi-getlasterror) to see why any failures happened.